# Android Studio 1.2.2 issue with JAVA_HOME

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm

I have installed JDK 1.8u45 in my machine. Earlier I was running Android Studio 1.1.0 in my machine with JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to JDK bin directory. It was working perfectly fine. But, I recently updated Android Studio to 1.2.2 and I am getting error with JAVA_HOME as JAVA_HOME doesn't point to a valid JVM installation.

Someone had raised a question about the same issue at following location, but there is no response.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172277

Besides, known issues page at Android Studio page doesn't site this issue. 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues

While I try to launch Android Studio, I get the above error.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the JAVA_HOME environment variable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx\bin to C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx

You don't need to navigate to bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change environment variable JAVA_HOME to JDK_HOME and dont include bin folder in the path. 
e.g JDK_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\JDK 1.8u45 "